# NavigationBar buttons not responding on a layout drawn from Service

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-service, android-windowmanager

I am trying to implement an `AlertWindow` kind of thing where I am using the instance of `WindowsManager` to add a `View` on it from a `Service`. The `View` is visible and accessible. But the back/home buttons on the on-screen `NavigationBar` don't seem to respond. I am new to Android.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
        mLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mLayout.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.Mainactivity,
                mLayout, true);
        mTvErrorMsg = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_error_msg);
        mChkBoxAppState = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox_app_state);
        mCancelBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_action);

        mEdtPin.addTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            mWindowManager.addView(mLayout, wmlp);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            SymLog.e(TAG, "Failed to add lock page.", e);

        }
```

Comment: Can you provide code or a link to the project

Comment: Try to override onBackPressed() fro back button and onKeyDown() for home button.

Comment: I doubt you can do that... you may consider adding a view in your layout for that purpose...

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed - Hey can you provide some guidelines regarding that?

Comment: If your issue is resolved, you may accept an answer or post your own answer and accept it. If you come to the community to get something, it is your responsibility to contribute to it back, that's how such community continues to serve with its good will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the below `LayoutParameters` solved my issue:

```
wmlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
wmlp.flags &= ~(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
wmlp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
wmlp.format = -1;
wmlp.token = null;
wmlp.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE;
```

Comment: You may accept this answer so that it doesn't look like unresolved to others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are defining the layoutparams right?

```
new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

This implies the the LinearLayout that you have will take up the parents full width/height. Perhaps change the view to WRAP_CONTENT so it will only take up as much as needed.

Likely this will require more work as it depends WHAT exactly you are trying show.